# Structural induction on binary trees

Tags: haskell, math, induction

Consider the following function definitions :

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)

sumLeaves :: Tree a -> Integer
sumLeaves (Leaf x) = 1 
sumLeaves (Node _ lt rt) = sumLeaves lt + sumLeaves rt 

sumNodes :: Tree a -> Integer
sumNodes (Leaf x) = 0 
sumNodes (Node _ lt rt) = 1 + sumNodes lt + sumNodes rt
```

Task: Prove by structural induction that for all finite trees t :: Tree a holds:

sumLeaves t = sumNodes t + 1

I now have:

```
sumLeaves t = sumNodes t + 1

I.A. t = (Tree 0) = (Leaf 0)

sumLeaves (Leaf 0) = 1 sumNodes (Leaf 0) + 1

0 + 1 = 1

1 = 1

I.V.: We assume that the statement holds for an arbitrary t.
```

I.S.:

Now what is the induction step, I really have problems with solving this last step.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the induction over natural numbers, where the induction step is assuming that some hypothesis holds for all numbers *less than n*, and then proving the hypothesis for n, structural induction step assumes that hypothesis holds for all structures that are *substructures of a given structure*.

In your case, correct assumption would be that the statement holds for trees `lt` and `rt` that are subtrees of the arbitrary `t@(Node x lt rt)`, and then proving the statement for `t`.